# Populating Object from DataTable with default value when DBNull

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, datatable, ternary-operator, dbnull

I am populating the customer object as shown below. How do I would I concisely code something like the following?

```
If IsDbNull(.Age) Then 
  .Age = 10
Else
  .Age = dataRow("Age")
End If
```

Here's the context I'd like to use it in:

```
Public Shared Function Retrieve() As List(Of Customer)

  Dim dt As DataTable = Dac.ExecuteDataTable("CustomerRetrieveAll", Nothing)
  Dim customerList As New List(Of Customer)

  For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows 
    customerList.Add(New Customer {
                       .CustomerId = CType(dr("CustomerID"), Integer),
                       .LastName = dr("LastName").ToString,
                       .Age = dr("Age").ToString,
                       .FirstName = dr("FirstName").ToString})  
  Next

  Return customerList 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace there is a function called `IIF`. It works by evaluating an expression and returning one value if the expression is true and another if false.

So

```
.Age = IIF(dr("Age") = DBNull.Value, 10, dr("Age").ToString())
```

In newer versions of Visual Studio (2008 ~), this is available by default without import an import (`IIF` was a function, the new `If` is an operator):

```
.Age = If(dr("Age") = DBNull.Value, 10, dr("Age").ToString())
```

If it wasn't `DBNull`, but just `Nothing`, you could use the null-coalescing operator:

```
Dim val = If(objectThatMightBeNothing, DefaultValueToUse)
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

```
.Age = IIf(dr("age") is DbNull, 10, dr("age"))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What value the age can have if it contains null?
I suggest using Nullable(Of Integer) for Age.

Also, compare it against DBNull.Value (which is used for comparison in case the underlying field contains null value).